# Magento Connect Manager not opening

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-connect-manager

I am trying to access **Magento Connect Manager** it is not opening, it is showing blank page. What am I supposed to do?

Please help

Comment: Please provide your magento version with any error log if present and  any activity after which this issue raised. Welcome to magento community.

Answer (score 0):

[It's not safe to use Magento connect for installing extension , click this link for more information.](https://www.integer-net.com/why-modules-shouldnt-be-installed-via-magento-connect-manager/)

in the worst case, if you want immediate solution , Alternatively you can install the extension through FTP (like FileZilla). You can paste the extension key [in this unofficial link](http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php) and you can download the extension files. Let me know if you find any problems in this.

**Note** : As this is unofficial 3rd party site, there is no guarantee about security. but i tested many extensions, i did't faced any security problems....