# Error on connect manager

Tags: magento-connect-manager

When I click on Magento Connect --> Magento Connect Manager it replies with

> Cannot connect to host: *name.domain.com*

Can't find any other configurations to do

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento Connect Manager not opening](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/148749/magento-connect-manager-not-opening)

Comment: How to install Magento Connect Manager on my site in such case?

Answer (score 1):

[It's not safe to use Magento connect for installing extension , click this link for more information.](https://www.integer-net.com/why-modules-shouldnt-be-installed-via-magento-connect-manager/)

in the worst case, if you want immediate solution , Alternatively you can install the extension through FTP (like FileZilla). You can paste the extension key [in this unofficial link](http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php) and you can download the extension files. Let me know if you find any problems in this.

**Note** : As this is unofficial 3rd party site, there is no guarantee about security. but i tested many extensions, i did't faced any security problems....